# ionic cordova resources keeps using default image instead of custom images

Tags: cordova, resources, ionic3

I have been working on an AngularJS 1.5, Cordova cli v 8, and ionic cli v2 app for a while.

I upgraded my ionic cli to version 3.

I wanted to take advantage of the new ionic cordova resources command so I can generate the new splash screens for the iPhoneX etc.

I updated my resources/icon.png file and resources/splash.png to the new specifications: 1024x1024 and
2732×2732px.

I ran the command ionic cordova resources and it did generate some new images and updated the config.xml file but it used the default logo instead of my custom one.

I am not sure what I am going wrong.

**My ionic info**:

```
[WARN] Error with .\www\lib\ionic\version.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND, trying .\bower.json.

cli packages: (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.5.6
local packages:

Cordova Platforms : android 6.2.3 ios 4.5.0 windows 4.4.2
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.5
System:

Node : v6.11.0
npm  : 5.6.0
OS   : Windows 10
Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : C:\Android\sdk
Misc:

backend : pro
```

**cordova requirements**

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-26,android-25,android-24,Google Inc.:Google APIs:24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-20,android-19,android-18,android-17
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: not installed
Cordova tooling for iOS requires Apple macOS

Requirements check results for windows:
Windows OS: installed Windows 10
MSBuild Tools: installed 14.0
Visual Studio: installed 14.0
Windows SDK: installed 10.0
Windows Phone SDK: installed 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you keep your old logo anywhere in the folder? Please remove all your old images and try it again.